# Find the radius of convergence of a polynomial with limited terms

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

The complete question is to find the Taylor series for $f(x)=x^5+3x^3+x$,centered at $a=3$ and then to find the associated radius of convergence R.

The Taylor series is straight forward and I get:

$327 + 487(x-3) + 297(x-3)^2 + 93(x-3)^3+15(x-3)^3$ + few more terms then $0$

Since this series ends at $n=6$, (since the derivatives go to zero after that) can I safely say that the series converges for ALL x, therefore R=$\infty$?

Comment: Short answer: yes. You should be able to see why by looking at the definition of convergence.

Comment: I did look at the 3 possibilities, but it's not clear from that theorem that it could not be the third case.

Answer (score 2):

Because a polynomial is differentiable infinitely many times and the remainder of the taylor sequence goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity (consider that $R_n$ is  defined in term of the $n+1$th derivative of $f(x)$) then the taylor series is convergent

Comment: but the question was about the radius of convergence.

Comment: The remainder is $0$ from the sixth term on for every $x$, so the series converges for every $x$, so the radius of convergence is infinite.